# My data is not being stored in my database

Tags: php

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code.  I am trying to get it to take the input from

```
<form id="contact-form" action="emails.php" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Please enter your email address" name="emailz" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="contact-submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

and have it saved into my database.

Here is my PHP file:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "poweilup";
$password = "bloop";
$dbname = "poweilup_emails";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO emails(addressEmail) VALUES($_POST '$emailz')";
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Where have you ever seen anything similar to this `VALUES($_POST '$emailz')`?

Comment: Not to mention the fact that you're setting up the query, but never run it? Also not using prepared statements and inserting POST data directly into your database?

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing guys. I have about 30 minutes of PHP coding and have just thrown together random things I've found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use MySQLi in a safe way, it's best to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). This will prevent your users from inserting SQL injection or, possibly by mistake, inserting characters that can cause problems to your MySQL server.

As you can see in the script below, I'm first preparing the SQL query, using a placeholder "?" for the item variable. After I'm binding the parameter(variable) to this placeholder.

Now the query is setup correctly, it's time to execute it. It's always a good habit to close anything left open once done, as it will free up memory that's no longer in use.

```
<?php

/* DB Info */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "poweilup";
$password = "bloop";
$dbname = "poweilup_emails";

/* MySQLi Object */
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Prepare query */
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO emails (addressEmail) VALUES (?)")){

    /* Bind POST data */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['emailz']);

    /* Run query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* Close connection */
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: What is `:?` supposed to be? `mysqli` uses just `?`.

Comment: @tadman Yup. My mistake. I'm used to using `PDO()` myself. That's why I mixed it up.

Comment: PDO's named placeholders are a lot more convenient, it's true.

Comment: The revised version here worked for me! Plus, with your explanation I actually feel like I understand what everything is doing! Thanks guys!

Comment: You're welcome. Though @JayBlanchard deserves some credit to. Without him I didn't realise I should explain what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do the insert -

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "poweilup";
$password = "bloop";
$dbname = "poweilup_emails";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `emails`(`addressEmail`) VALUES(?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

$email = $_POST('emailz');
$stmt->execute();
```

First you prepare the query and leave placeholders for the item variables. The you [bind each parameter(variable)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and then declare them. Finally you execute the query.

Comment: Tried this and got "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/poweilup/public_html/emails.php on line 18"

Comment: Also means turning on [exception reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

First check if the user hasn't missed anything:

```
if (isset($_POST['emailz']) { //code here.. };
```

In the `code here...` section, store the value of `emailz` in a variable like this:

```
$emailz = $_POST['emailz'];
```

Of course this may be insecure for more important data like passwords. You should use the `hash()` function then.

For inserting the variable in DB, try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `user` (emailz) VALUES ('$emailz')"; $result = mysql_query($query);     //inserts the variable in the DB.
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Without [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) this is [extremely dangerous](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're also using the horrible `mysql_query` interface when the question is using `mysqli`.

Comment: Giving this a shot. However, I noticed you put "&_POST" instead of "$_POST" in the first line.

Comment: sorry,i was typing fast!